# InnoDB tables inaccessible after reboot

Tags: mysql, linux, innodb

After reboot each time, I can't see my InnoDB table. However, when use command mode I can see my tables, but cannot access to it.

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_xpl_ticket |
+----------------------+
| active_list          |
| bill_block           |
| bill_block_list      |
| block                |
| block_list           |
| box                  |
| cisco_switch         |
| mac_add              |
| mac_change           |
| month                |
| new_connect          |
| new_user             |
| open                 |
| package_change       |
| paid_list            |
| pay                  |
| problem              |
| re_open              |
| refund               |
|  ticket              |
| user                 |
| user_log             |
+----------------------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I want to access a table it says table doesn't exist;

```
mysql> select * from active_list;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'xpl_ticket.active_list' doesn't exist
```

Edit by RolandoMySQLDBA

Please run the following in MySQL:

```
SELECT VERSION();
SELECT CONCAT('[',table_name,']') tbl_name
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='xpl_ticket';
```

Please run the following in the OS:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/xpl_ticket
ls -l
```

Hi [RolandoMySQLDBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba),

Thank you for your quick reply. Here is all those outputs.

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT CONCAT('[',table_name,']') tbl_name
-> FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='xpl_ticket';
+-------------------+
| tbl_name          |
+-------------------+
| [active_list]     |
| [bill_block]      |
| [bill_block_list] |
| [block]           |
| [block_list]      |
| [box]             |
| [cisco_switch]    |
| [mac_add]         |
| [mac_change]      |
| [month]           |
| [new_connect]     |
| [new_user]        |
| [open]            |
| [package_change]  |
| [paid_list]       |
| [pay]             |
| [problem]         |
| [re_open]         |
| [refund]          |
| [ticket]          |
| [user]            |
| [user_log]        |
+-------------------+
22 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

My data directory is not in "/var/lib/mysql" path. I have been changed it to "/var/www/xampp/mysql/data" path. So I am going to execute the following code.

```
Lurid / # cd /var/www/xampp/mysql/data/xpl_ticket/
Lurid xpl_ticket # ls -l
total 265
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9272 Jun  6 12:48 active_list.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8654 Jun  6 12:48 bill_block.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9272 Jun  6 12:48 bill_block_list.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8654 Jun  6 12:48 block.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9272 Jun  6 12:48 block_list.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8802 Jun  6 12:48 box.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8648 Jun  6 12:48 cisco_switch.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   65 Jun  6 12:48 db.opt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8690 Jun  6 12:48 mac_add.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8698 Jun  6 12:48 mac_change.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8618 Jun  6 12:48 month.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8716 Jun  6 12:48 new_connect.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9002 Jun  6 12:48 new_user.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8680 Jun  6 12:48 open.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8724 Jun  6 12:48 package_change.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8692 Jun  6 12:48 paid_list.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8592 Jun  6 12:48 pay.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8802 Jun  6 12:48 problem.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8670 Jun  6 12:48 refund.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8714 Jun  6 12:48 re_open.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8900 Jun  6 12:48 ticket.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8704 Jun  6 12:48 user.frm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8808 Jun  6 12:48 user_log.frm
```

Hi Mannoj

These tables are created in these same database.

I have some errors in my "/var/log/mysql/error.log". I don't understand what are those. Here are they ....

```
130611 12:41:28 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130611 12:41:29 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130611 12:41:30  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130611 12:41:31  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
130611 12:41:31 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130611 12:43:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130611 12:43:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130611 12:43:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130611 12:43:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
130611 12:43:15 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130611 12:43:15 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130611 12:43:15 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
130611 12:43:15  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130611 12:43:15  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130611 12:43:16  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
```

Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Was this table created in this same database server itself or copied from someother server?

Comment: We need additional information. I added the things I need you to run. Please run them and post the output inside the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `.frm` files. They are owned by `root root`.

They are supposed to be owned by `mysql mysql`

My guess is that you copied the data rather than use MySQL techniques to import.

Perhaps you should change the ownership of the entire data folder.

Please run the following commands:

```
cd /var/www/xampp/mysql/data
chown -R mysql:mysql *
```

Then restart mysql.

As for the error messages, the InnoDB System Tablespace (ibdata1) and the Redo Log Files (ib_logfile0,ib_logfile1) are being created.

From the above messages, my guess is that you did this something like this

- You had shutdown mysql
- You copied `/var/lib/mysql` to `/var/www/xampp/mysql/data`
- You started mysql
- mysqld did not see InnoDB Infrastructure files, so they were created

If you have an all-MyISAM database (every table uses the InnoDB storage engine) you can easily get away with copying data folders. You would still have to change file ownership to `mysql mysql`. If there are any InnoDB tables, you must copy the entire data folder, not just a database within the data folder.

## CAVEAT

Please note that running `SHOW TABLES;` simply walks across the current database telling you table names by looking at the `.frm` files without checking ownership or table validity. Once you actually perform some SQL again the table that all metadata checks against the table are done.